# LRU cache with async writes

Tags: multithreading, caching

I was just looking at bottlenecks in some code and thinking about the time taking to write/set/put a reference to a cache (which the code does when persisting an object to the database).

Are there any standard LRU cache libraries that do async put to the cache so that the thread can just move on - in my case return a success code for the database save?

I understand that this could mean a lookup on another thread a few milliseconds later might miss the cache opportunity but in this case that would be fine.

Or is the overhead of putting on a separate thread just too much?

Comment: Usually LRU caches are guarded by a single lock used by readers & writers. Since eviction is O(1), async writes is rarely the bottleneck. But if made concurrent via replay buffers, then read/write can be decoupled from the LRU policy. Then writes are about as fast as a concurrent hashmap, so again not the bottleneck to optimize. See [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine) and its predecessors for details.

Comment: Thanks! Can you make this an answer so I can tick it?